# Are anchor tags an option to index lazy loaded images?

Tags: seo, search, lazyloading

I am using a gallery that has lazy loading implemented. Only the thumb images are indexed by Google, the large images are not.

Functionality, for context: Many thumbs are displayed, when a thumb is clicked, the large image version is loaded from a "data-src" attribute.

If I include the large images as "href" attributes of anchor tags (which I hide with "display: none;"), will the large images be indexed well?